# Can''t disable autoprefixer in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, autoprefixer

My intention is not use autoprefixer in my Next.js project, due it comes configured by default in next.js, it is creating a huge amount of browser prefixes, I've read you can setup a false flag and it will disable autoprefixer but it is not working.

My next.config.js has these lines:

```
/** @format */

const nextTranslate = require('next-translate');

module.exports = {
  autoprefixer: false,
  ...nextTranslate(),
};
```

Comment: `autoprefixer: {}` I think it does the trick

Comment: It didn't work. After I restart locally or deploy the branch and check it, the CSS contains the preffixer.

Comment: You'll have to define your [custom PostCSS config](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#customizing-plugins) file to not use `autoprefixer`. It can't be done through `next.config.json`.